# Separando números em listas pares e ímpares - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Meu código precisa ler vários números e colocá-los em uma lista, depois, criar duas listas extras contendo apenas os valores pares e ímpares, respectivamente, da lista anterior.

Exemplo:

```
Entrada = [3, 7, 8, 11, 16, 20]
Saída = Lista completa: [3, 7, 8, 11, 16, 20]
        Lista de pares: [8, 16, 20]
        Lista de ímpares: [3, 7, 11]
```

Porém os valores não estão sendo adicionados nas listas de números pares e ímpares, qual é o problema do meu código?

```
valores = pares = impares = list()

while True:
    valores.append(int(input('Digite um valor: ')))

    continuar = ' '
    while continuar not in 'SN':
        continuar = str(input('Continuar? [S / N] ')).upper()[0]
    if continuar in 'N':
        break

print(f'Lista completa: {valores}')

for num in valores:
    if num % 2 == 0:
        pares.append(num)
    else:
        impares.append(num)

print(f'Lista de pares: {pares}')
print(f'Lista de ímpares: {impares}')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema do seu código está em

```py
valores = pares = impares = list()
```

Isso gera apenas uma lista mas com três variáveis a referenciando. Assim, o loop de verificação de par e ímpar nunca para de rodar pois elementos são sempre adicionados a cada iteração.
A solução para isso é definir três listas separadas:

```py
valores = []
pares = []
impares = []
```

Answer (score 1):

Para resolver esta questão você deve implementar um algoritmo que `monte` uma lista formada por todos os valores `digitados` pelo usuário, em seguida `separe` os valores `ímpares` dos `pares` e, posteriormente os exibam em listas separadas.

Para isso você pode implementar o seguinte algoritmo...

```
# Criando uma lista com todos os valores digitados:
valores = list(map(int, input('Digite todos os valores desejados: ').split()))

# Separando os valores em pares e ímpares:
impares = list()
pares = list()
for c in valores:
    if c % 2 != 0:
        impares.append(c)
    else:
        pares.append(c)

# Exibindo as listas de valores pares e ímpares:
print(f'\033[32mOs números pares são: {pares}')
print(f'Os números ímpares são: {impares}')
```

[Veja aqui](https://repl.it/join/jmeakqaf-solkarped) o funcionamento do programa.

Observe que quando você executa este programa você recebe a seguinte `solicitação`...

```
Digite todos os valores desejados:
```

Neste momento você tem que digitar **todos** os valores desejados na **mesma** linha, separados por **apenas 1 espaço**, tal como exemplificado abaixo.

```
4 6 8 9 12 23
```

Depois de ter inserido todos os valores é só digitar `enter`. Neste momento o programa irá separar os valores `impares` e `pares` e, posteriormente, exibi-los.

Observe também, que para encerrar a `inserção` de valores na `lista`, basta pressionar a tecla `enter`.

Answer (score 0):

É como o colega Murgalha falou, veja se assim não te atende melhor:

```
lista_completa = [3, 7, 8, 11, 16, 20]
lista_pares = []
lista_impares = []

for c in lista_completa:
  if c % 2 == 0:
    lista_pares.append(c)
  else:
    lista_impares.append(c)

print(lista_impares)
print(lista_pares)
```

Comment: Sua resposta não leva em conta que o algoritmo deve ser implementado de maneira a receber n valores de acordo com o usuário.

Answer (score 0):

Eu sei que já faz anos, mas eu fiz de um jeito que ficasse mais parecido ao que o nosso amigo quis fazer em seu código:

```
valores = []
pares = []
impares = []

while True:
  valores.append(int(input('Digite um valor: ')))

  continuar = ' '
  while continuar not in 'SN':
    continuar = str(input('Continuar? [S / N] ')).upper()[0]
  if continuar in 'N':
    break

for i in range(len(valores)):
  if valores[i] % 2 == 0:
    pares.append(valores[i])
  else:
    impares.append(valores[i])

    

print(f'Lista completa: {valores}')
print(f'Lista de pares: {pares}')
print(f'Lista de ímpares: {impares}')
```

Answer (score -1):

O cara ja deve estar trabalhando na NAZA mas pra mim que sou iniciante e caí aqui de paraquedas, vou deixar minha solução indicando também o maior e menor numero da lista completa.

```
lista_completa = [3, 7, 8, 11, 16, 20]
lista_impares = []
lista_pares = []

print('Maior numero', max(lista_completa))
print('Menor numero', min(lista_completa))

for number in range(3, 21):
    if number % 2 != 0:
        lista_impares.append(number)
    if number % 2 != 1:
        lista_pares.append(number)

print('Pares', lista_pares)
print('Ímpares', lista_impares)

#Saida
Maior numero 20
Menor numero 3
Pares [4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]
Ímpares [3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19]
```